# Is there any way in Preview on Mac OS X to make the elliptical tool hollow (like a lasso) not solid?

Tags: macos

Using Preview tool for images in Mac OS X is there any way to make the elliptical tool hollow (like a lasso) not solid?

Currently if I use the elliptical tool it seems to only produce a solid ellipse. I’m looking for a hollow ellipse so you can read the content it is circling. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In the toolbar  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>    <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>A</kbd>   you can select Line width/style, Line colour & Fill colour, independently. A square with a diagonal strikethrough is 'none'

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Tetsujin.  Thankyou greatly for the reply.  I cannot see the options "Line width/style, Line colour & Fill colour" in the preview tool.  The 12 icons I can see are labelled, in order: Selection tool
Instant Alpha
Sketch
Shape
text
sign
Adjust colour
Adjust size
Shape style
Border colour
Fill colour
Text style, Are you able to provide instruction using those names.  Thankyou.

Comment: Fill Colour - set to None, i.e. a blank square with a diagonal stripe through it, top left of the swatches. Added to answer...

Comment: Done!   Awesome.   Thankyou sir!